# Background Service not working in android PIE version

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm making an android app in which i'm storing the connected time and disconnected time of a WiFi but when i remove the app from the background it does not respond.
I'm using foreground service it is working with other devices but not working in mi phone's and also not working in API 28 PIE VERSION.
Can anyone tell me how to do it.

Comment: Did you fine any solution?